# Can't send mail

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail, smtp

I can't seem to figure out how to get my server to send out an email. I've installed postfix for a send-only server, and every time I run `mail -s "hello world" myemailaddress@outlook.com`, I get at timeout error. Here's my `mail.log` contents:

```
Jun  9 22:09:14 ubuntu postfix/master[1292]: daemon started -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun  9 22:09:14 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1308]: 5F4DD2402B3: from=<jacob@ubuntu.attlocal.net>, size=351, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  9 22:09:45 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1317]: connect to 4c83721c8bbbca488ecc043c2e9f68.pamx1.hotmail.com[65.54.188.78]:25: Connection timed out
Jun  9 22:10:15 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1317]: connect to 4c83721c8bbbca488ecc043c2e9f68.pamx1.hotmail.com[65.54.188.109]:25: Connection timed out
$Connection timed out)
Jun  9 22:14:14 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1308]: CC89B2402D6: from=<jacob@ubuntu.attlocal.net>, size=350, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  9 22:14:26 ubuntu postfix/pickup[1307]: E10C92404AE: uid=1000 from=<jacob@ubuntu.attlocal.net>
Jun  9 22:14:26 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[1824]: E10C92404AE: message-id=<20150610031426.E10C92404AE@git.ghostlyco.de>
Jun  9 22:14:27 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1308]: E10C92404AE: from=<jacob@ubuntu.attlocal.net>, size=352, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

As you can see it times out when trying to send the message. I've tried reinstall `postfix`, ensured that port 25 is open on my server and my firewall, checked to see if port 25 was open from an outside network using [this website](http://canyouseeme.org/)... All the standard stuff, I think. No idea why this is happening.

The ultimate goal is to get `postfix` working so that my GitLab server will send out notification emails. It's installed from source, if that helps.

I have next to no idea what I'm doing with command line and Linux stuff, so please try to explain like I'm an idiot :)

Comment: I had a similar problem when trying to send test messages to gmail, I had to have forward and reverse dns pointers and MX records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had recently setup postfix to do simple email relay via gmail.

I followed this guide to do it and had no problems:
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/

I am not sure if your requirement is just as simple as mine, but you may want to give this setup a try.

Comment: Will the "from" address for these emails by my gmail address then? Or can I make it whatever I want?

Comment: Alright, so I set it up to send through gmail but it's sending with my email address, and I'd prefer if it sent from git@git.ghostlyco.de (which isn't a real email, it's just my git@ my git server's domain. Is this possible?

Comment: Alright, I was able to use this method to configure with a free custom domain email provider, zoho.com. Works perfectly. Thanks much!